# Bulk insert and ignore if a document already exist

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a script that scraps a website everyday at a specific hour. I convert the data received into an array of objects like this:

```
Items = [ 
    {
      title: "some title", 
      url: "someurl.com/something" , 
      description: "some description"
     },
     {...} ,
     {...}
]
```

Then I use a foreach loop to insert each object of the array into MongoDB:

```
Items.forEach( item => Collection.create(item));
```

Now every day when the script runs, it gets all the previous data that have been already inserted into the database and new ones. 
I want to insert only new objects into the database.
I tried different ways but it does not work.

Please someone can tell me how I can get it to work?
Also the forEach loop I use to insert to the database I am sure there is better way to do it.

Comment: Thanks Filburt. I did not know. I will consider this next time.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Update`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html) with [`upsert`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#upsert-option) enabled instead of just inserting into the database.

```
var your_document = { .... };

Model.update(your_document, your_document, options, callback)
// is sent as
Model.update(query, { $set: ......}, options, callback)
```